# country is getting appended twice in storefront URL(spartacus)

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I'm having trouble with the basesite service. We currently have three websites: global, cn (China), and tw (Taiwan) (Taiwan)
To pick the region, we have a drop-down menu on the global site. Using baseservice(spartacus), the selected region is set.

this.baseSiteService.setActive(region);

localhost:4200/cn/cn When the above line has run, appears in the URL

Could someone please explain how it is appended twice in the url and how to override this?

Comment: Does this problem happen in OOTB Spartacus, or in a customized app? Especially, did you customize anything related to the site context (services, configs)? If yes, what did you customize and how?

Comment: This is happening in the sparatacus application and we don't have any services or configs related to site context. We simply set the region in the above mentioned base service

Answer (score 0):

You said in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72402840/country-is-getting-appended-twice-in-storefront-urlspartacus?noredirect=1#comment128395597_72402840) that you "don't have any services or configs related to site context". So I guess what you see in the URL by default are 2 different site contexts: `baseSite` and `language`, which "by coincidence" have the same values pairwise):
`localhost:4200/<baseSite>/<language>`

I guess what you want to achieve in this case is to have an URL of the shape `localhost:4200/<baseSite>`. This can be achieved in 2 ways, depending on whether you're using static or automatic site-context configuration.

You can configure which site contexts should appear in the URL in 2 ways:

1. if you're using CMS-driven site context configuration in Spartacus (aka. [automatic site-context-configuration](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/automatic-context-configuration/)), then you need to configure it in CMS Backoffice tool. As in the screenshot below, for each of your basesites go to `WCMS -> Website -> <select your base site> -> Administration (tab) -> URL Encoding Attributes` and put there only the value `storefront` (get rid of `language` or anything else there). And save the changes.
   [image: How to configure URL encoding attributes]
2. if you're using [static site-context configuration](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/static-context-configuration) in Spartacus, then you need to provide the following static config in your app:

   ```
   provideConfig({
     urlParameters: ['baseSite']
   })
   ```

#### References:

- [Automatic Site Configuration Detection from URL](https://microlearning.opensap.com/media/Automatic+Site+Configuration+Detection+from+URL+-+SAP+Commerce+Cloud/1_erxf2j1r) (demo video)
- [Spartacus docs on Site-context configuration](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/context-configuration/)